# Why does this NSMutableAttributedString addAttribute work only if I use a mutableCopy

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsattributedstring, nsmutablecopying

I have the following code :

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attrS = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"• Get Tested Son"];
NSMutableAttributedString *boldS = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Son"];

[boldS addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:SOMEBOLDFONT range:NSMakeRange(0, boldS.length)];

[attrS replaceCharactersInRange:[attrS.string rangeOfString:boldS.string]
           withAttributedString:boldS];
```

As you can see, I want to bold the `Son` part. This does not work if I do the above statements but only works if I do :

```
[[attrS mutableCopy] replaceCharactersInRange:[attrS.string rangeOfString:boldS.string]
                         withAttributedString:boldS];
```

What might be the reason for that?

Comment: How does it not work? And where do you call `addAttribute` ?

Comment: I don't see where you bold you `NSMutableAttributedString` : all you do is change a string for the same string. Is there a `addAttributes` or something like that that you forgot to post here ?

Comment: Let me update it. Thanks.

Comment: I can't replicate this. Is this real code that you've run and had the problem with?

Comment: As with Chuck, I ran this code and it works perfectly. You've made a mistake elsewhere.

Comment: What is SOMEBOLDFONT? Are you sure you didn't screw that up?

Comment: make sure your `attrS` is actually `NSMutableAttributedString` not `NSAttributedString`

Comment: I can totally understand that you cannot replicate. What I'm looking for is what exact difference would an NSMutableAttributedString mutable do? Does it copy the pointer?

Comment: Intuitively enough, `mutableCopy` creates a copy of the receiver — that is, a new object that has the same attributes as the receiver — that is mutable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`addAttribute` works regardless of whether you take a `mutableCopy`. Your question is based on a false assumption. It therefore has no answer.

Run this:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attrS = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"• Get Tested Son"];
NSMutableAttributedString *boldS = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Son"];

UIFont *someBoldFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:23.0f];
[boldS addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:someBoldFont range:NSMakeRange(0, boldS.length)];

NSMutableAttributedString *attrSCopy = [attrS mutableCopy];

[attrS replaceCharactersInRange:[attrS.string rangeOfString:boldS.string]
           withAttributedString:boldS];
[attrSCopy replaceCharactersInRange:[attrS.string rangeOfString:boldS.string]
           withAttributedString:boldS];

NSLog(@"%@", [attrS isEqual:attrSCopy] ? @"equal" : @"different");
```

It will output `equal`. Comment out the `replaceCharactersInRange:` for either `attrS` or `attrSCopy` and it will output `different`.